# Java | How Garbage Collector Ignores array memory with no reference

Tags: java, arrays, memory-management, garbage-collection

My understanding is that Garbage Collector collects memory which are not referenced, and that the array reference (eg int []a = new int [5]) only points to the first element (Do let me know if this is not correct.)

How does Garbage collector know not to collect and free the memory locations allocated to element 2nd to last?

Comment: You are confusing C with Java.

Comment: You can't point to an element in an array, you can only retain the array reference and an index as a pair. Since you must always point to the header, there is no confusion in GCing.

Answer (score 7):

> the array reference (eg int []a = new int [5]) only points to the first element

This is incorrect<sup>1</sup>.

The array reference points to a Java object that has a special `length` field that will (in this case) contain the value `5`.  The GC knows how to find that field, and knows what it means.

In this case the `int[]` cannot contain any references, so the GC only needs to copy the array contents when it relocates the array.  If this was an `Integer[]`, then the array *could* contain references, and the GC would (if necessary<sup>2</sup>) mark and relocate them as well.

---

<sup>1 - It would be correct for C and C++, but those are *different* programming languages.  You can't correctly infer how the Java GC works based on a mental model of C or C++.</sup>

<sup>2 - This depends on the kind of collection being performed.  If the GC is collecting just the "new" space and the references are to objects in an older space, then the GC won't mark them.</sup>